# How to bind to a list of images

Tags: xaml, binding, windows-phone

I have changed my code to this:

the view:

```
<phone:Panorama.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ScrollViewer Width="800" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Margin="0,50,0,0">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <ListBox x:Name="list_of_images" ItemsSource="{Binding ImagesUrls}">
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <Image Width="300" Height="300" Source="{Binding}"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        </ListBox>

                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" 
                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                   Loaded="TextBlock_Loaded_1"
                                   Margin="50,0,0,0"
                                   FontSize="23"
                                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                   Width="360"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                   Foreground="Black"/>

                        <TextBox Text="{Binding ContactEmail}" 
                                   Grid.Row="2" 
                                BorderBrush="Black"
                                 Width="340"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                 BorderThickness="1"
                                  Margin="40,0,0,0"
                                   Foreground="Black" />

                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Body}" 
                                   Grid.Row="3" 
                                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                   Foreground="Black"
                                   Margin="50,5,0,0"
                                   Width="360"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                   FontSize="20" />
                    </Grid>
```

and I build a new object with different properties, with one of the properties being a list of strings which represents the imageurls, but I cannot get the images to show? [image: Image of Object]

[image: list of objects]

I have attached screenshots, what in my xaml must I change so that I can display the images, cause at the moment it doesn't show any images but it shows all the other details

code for populating collection:

```
   ObservableCollection<ClassifiedAds> klasifiseerd_source = new ObservableCollection<ClassifiedAds>();

  ImagesClassifieds new_Classifieds = new ImagesClassifieds();

  ObservableCollection<string> gallery_images = new ObservableCollection<string>();


   new_Classifieds.Title = klasifiseerd_source[0].Title;
   new_Classifieds.ContactEmail = klasifiseerd_source[0].ContactEmail;
   new_Classifieds.Body = klasifiseerd_source[0].Body;


         foreach (var item in klasifiseerd_source[0].Gallery.Images)
        {
            var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GalleryImages>(item.ToString());
            gallery_images.Add(deserialized.ImageUrl);
            //new_Classifieds.ImageUrls.Add(deserialized.ImageUrl);
        }

      new_Classifieds.ImageUrls = gallery_images;

        // classifiedPanorama.ItemsSource = new_list;

        new_Classifieds_list.Add(new_Classifieds);

        classifiedPanorama.ItemsSource = new_Classifieds_list;


public class ImagesClassifieds
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ContactEmail { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> ImageUrls { get; set; }

}
```

[image: imageurl format]

here is the imageurl format, this works (in another par tof my app I simply bind to 1 image in this format and it works perfectly)

Comment: How would you bind a list of images to a single Image control? Are you perhaps talking about an Image control in the ItemTemplate of an ItemsControl? Maybe this is of some help: [Binding to Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#binding_to_collections).

Comment: sory would you mind helping me, so I added this:    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Gallery}">
                                <Image Source="{Binding Images}"  />
                            </ListBox>                                                              but its still not working, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do your Image URLs look like? Please show the code where you populate the ImageUrls collection. And did you take a look at the Output Window in Visual Studio? Perhaps it is showing some binding error messages.

Comment: No binding issues, however is it possible to do a listbox itemtemplate, inside an panorama itemstemplate? but I think my xaml binding code is just wrong

Comment: Except that you shouldn't set `Height="Auto"` on the first grid row (which contains the ListBox) the XAML looks ok. For the URLs, have you ever checked if they are really valid? Perhaps just take the first of them and do a simple teest with it: `<Image Source="<url>"/>`.

Comment: yes I just tested and it works, its only the list of images not working

Comment: In your XAML you bind `ItemsSource="{Binding ImagesUrls}"`. Should be `ItemsSource="{Binding ImageUrls}"`, without `s`, I guess. But then you would have seen a binding error message, right?

Comment: yo, thanx for the help, but I found a "hack" or whatever you want to call it.

Comment: Didn't you understand my last comment? You were just using a wrong property name in the `ItemsSource` binding.

Comment: I did change it, and it didn't work, and I also didn't get a binding exception

Answer (score 2):

Depending on whether you want to just display a list of images or if you also want to be able to select them, you may either choose an ItemsControl or a ListBox. In both case you have to define a DataTemplate that controls how each item is displayed.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

or

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Then you should think about how you define your item class. Just in case you want to be able to dynamically add or remove images from the list and let the UI be automatically updated, you should use an `ObservableCollection` as container type. As there is a built-in type conversion from `string` to `ImageSource` (the type of the Image control's `Source` property), you may simply use an `ObservableCollection<string>`.

```
public class Gal
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Images { get; set; }
}
```

You may create an instance of that class like so:

```
var gallery = new Gal();
gallery.Images = new ObservableCollection<string>(
    Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures", "*.jpg"));
```

Now you may directly bind to that instance by simply setting the DataContext of your Window (or wherever the image list should be shown) to this instance:

```
DataContext = gallery;
```

Note the binding declaration in the ItemsControl or ListBox above was `{Binding Images}`. If you really have to have a property `Gallery` (which I assume is in MainWindow) and bind like `{Binding Gallery.Images}` you may set the DataContext like this:

```
DataContext = this;
```

Comment: thanx for helping, could you please take a look at my updated code?

Answer (score 0):

so I basically created a loaded event on the listbox and added this code

```
  private void list_of_images_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox lst = (ListBox)sender;
        lst.ItemsSource = new_Classifieds_list[0].ImageUrls;
    }
```

which binds the itemssource of the listbox to the list of imageurls. since I cannot access the listbox from codebehind due to it being inside the panorama's itemstemplate