# Image Loading Method how to remove old picture to avoid duplicate

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, grid

I have an image editing program, and I have a bug where the old picture isn't removed after saving an image and loading the new one, the new one loads properly in the thumbnail. So now there is two copies of the same picture, without even removing the old one. Thumbnails.clear works but thumbnails.remove doesn't seem to do anything and I kinda want to keep the other ones.

I have tried to change the addpicturebutton method to add Before DynamicGrid.Remove(currentImage) but that didn't change anything either.

The original loadimage pictures is called in the main method with

```
 ImagePicker.LoadImages(ImageFile);
```

Imagepicker is defined like this in the xaml part of the Mainwindow

```
 <userControls:ImageEditor x:Name="ImagePicker"
                                  Visibility="{Binding ImageEditorVisibility, FallbackValue=Hidden, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" Margin="0,0,860,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="150" MinWidth="150"/>
```

This is the class where I am attempting to access the imagepicker.loadimages method

```
UcImageGrabbedControls.OnImageSaved += () => ImagePicker.LoadImages(integrationMode.PreloadImageFile);
```

The loadimage method looks like this

```
public void UpdateImages(string image)
{
    thumbNails.Children.Remove(addPictureButton(image));
    thumbNails.Children.Add(addPictureButton(image));
}


public Button addPictureButton(string image)
    {

        Image currentImage = new Image();



          BitmapImage image1 = new BitmapImage();
            image1.BeginInit();
image1.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
            image1.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            image1.UriSource = new Uri(image);
            image1.EndInit();
            currentImage.Source = image1;
            currentImage.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
        string fileNames = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(image);

        Grid DynamicGrid = new Grid();
        DynamicGrid.Width = 400;
        DynamicGrid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        DynamicGrid.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        DynamicGrid.ShowGridLines = true;
        DynamicGrid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightSteelBlue);

        // Create Columns
        ColumnDefinition gridCol1 = new ColumnDefinition();
        ColumnDefinition gridCol2 = new ColumnDefinition();
        ColumnDefinition gridCol3 = new ColumnDefinition();
        DynamicGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(gridCol1);
        DynamicGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(gridCol2);
        DynamicGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(gridCol3);

        // Create Rows
        RowDefinition gridRow1 = new RowDefinition();
        DynamicGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRow1);

        var fileTextBlock = new TextBlock();
        fileTextBlock.Text = fileNames;
        fileTextBlock.FontSize = 14;
        fileTextBlock.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
        fileTextBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        fileTextBlock.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        Grid.SetRow(fileTextBlock, 0);
        Grid.SetColumn(fileTextBlock, 0);

        DynamicGrid.Children.Add(currentImage);
        DynamicGrid.Children.Add(fileTextBlock);

        var newButton = new MyButton();
        newButton.Content = DynamicGrid;
        newButton.Name = "button";
        newButton.Height = 100;
        newButton.Background = Brushes.Chocolate;
        newButton.ImageRef = image;
        newButton.Command = ChangePicture;
        newButton.CommandParameter = newButton;
        fileTextBlock.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
        fileTextBlock.Height = newButton.Height - 50;

        return newButton;
    }
```

The sent in file ALWAYS has the same filename as the one sent in originally, so that shouldn't be the problem and the image has been saved in the folder before that happens.

Edit: I am currently working on finding out the indexes of the images based on the image.source but currently struggling, this is what I got this far

```
public void UpdateImages(string image)
{

    int indexToRemove;
    foreach(var item in thumbNails.Children)
    {
        var element = item as Button;
        var grid = element.Content as Grid;
        TextBlock block = null;
        foreach(var child in grid.Children)
        {
            if (image = child.Contains(image))
            {
                child = (Image)child;
                indexToRemove = 
                thumbNails.Children.RemoveAt(indexToRemove);
            }
        }


    }
    thumbNails.Children.Add(addPictureButton(image));
```

Comment: `thumbNails.Children.Remove(image)` can obviously not work with `image` being a string. You have to remove the appropriate Button which was added by `thumbNails.Children.Add(addPictureButton(image))` before. It's time for you to make yourself familiar with MVVM. Then create a view model that represents a collection of image buttons. Visualize them in an ItemsControl. You may start reading here: [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).

Comment: That sounds super complicated and a long rewrite of my current code, isn't there anything simpler?

Comment: It makes everything far easier than what you have right now. It would bring an architecture into your application, and you would get rid of creating UI elements in code, which is bad practice in the WPF world.

Comment: Take e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18351268/1136211) as a very basic example for the first steps.

Comment: I will look into it. I'm just an intern but it's a great idea to learn MVVM properly. I've just got handed a huge Project and needed to fix this tiny thing in a really messy/bad Project and just need a Quick fix for this somehow

Comment: You may probably just keep a `Dictionary<string, Button>`, but I didn't say that...

Comment: Haha, could you show me quickly how to do that Dictionary? It's Another thing I need to learn ^^

Comment: Add a member variable like `private readonly Dictionary<string, Button> imageButtons = new Dictionary<string, Button>();`. Then if you have created a Button for an image string, call `imageButtons[image] = button` and get the Button by `var button = imageButtons[image]` or `TryGetValue`. Read the online documentation first.

Comment: This worked! Please post it as an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: Sorry, that's just too bad for an answer. As said, I didn't tell you that.