# How can I configure the click event handler of a control for removing itself at its object creation?

Tags: c#, wpf

Suppose I have two classes: `MainWindow` and `MainWindowViewModel`. There is a control called `ButtonControl` in `MainWindow` with a click event handler that calls a function in `MainWindowViewModel`. The function creates Images and then adds them to some WrapPanel's children in the MainWindow. I want to configure a click event handler to the Image Controls at the time they are created so that I can remove the controls from MainWindow when I click on it (MouseLeftButtonUp). How can I do?

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Windows ...>
<Grid>
<Button Name="ButtonControl" Click="ButtonControl_Click" />
<WrapPanel Name="AttachedPhotosWP" />
</Grid>
</Windows>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private MainWindowViewModel _vm = new MainWindowViewModel();
    public MainWindowViewModel VM{ get { return _vm; } set { _vm= value; } }
    public MainWindow()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       this.DataContext = VM;      
    }
    private void ButtonControl_Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        VM.ImageCreation(this);
    }
}
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```cs
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    /* Some other codes */


    public void ImageCreation(MainWindow MW)
    {
         OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
         openFileDialog.Multiselect = true;
         openFileDialog.Title = "Select Images...";
         if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
         {
              foreach (var file in openFileDialog.FileNames)
              {
                  try
                  {
                      Image img = new Image();
                      BitmapImage imgSrc = new BitmapImage();
                      imgSrc.BeginInit();
                      Uri fileUri = new Uri(file, UriKind.Absolute);
                      imgSrc.UriSource = fileUri;
                      imgSrc.DecodePixelWidth = 100;
                      imgSrc.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                      imgSrc.EndInit();
                      img.Source = imgSrc;
                      img.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
                      img.Height = 70;
                      img.Margin = new Thickness(4, 4, 4, 4);
                      img.MouseLeftButtonUp += ????
                      img.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
                      MW.AttachedPhotosWP.Children.Add(img);
                  }
                  catch (SecurityException ex) { }
                  catch (Exception ex) { }     
              }
          }
    }

}
```

Comment: As a  note, passing a MainWindow reference to the `ImageCreation` method is not MVVM. You should not call that a view model. You should instead use an ItemsControl which has its ItemsSource property bound to an ObservableCollection. See e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18351268/1136211

Comment: The Image element in the ItemTemplate may than have a mouse event handler that removes it from the source collection.

Comment: @Clemens how to let the code like MVVM more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing a MainWindow reference to the ImageCreation method and creating UI elements in code behind is not at all MVVM.

A basic MVVM solution would use an ItemsControl with an ItemTemplate that contains the Image element. The ItemsSource property of the ItemsControl is bound to an `ObservableCollection<ImageSource>`. The Image element has an event handler that removes itself from that collection.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ImageFiles}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}"
                   Height="70" Margin="4"
                   MouseLeftButtonUp="Image_MouseLeftButtonUp"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
...
<Button Content="Load Images..." Click="LoadButton_Click"/>
```

The MainWindow class and the view model would look like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = viewModel;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void LoadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog.Multiselect = true;
        openFileDialog.Title = "Select Images...";
        openFileDialog.Filter = "JPEG Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|PNG Files (*.png)|*.png";

        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            viewModel.LoadImages(openFileDialog.FileNames);
        }
    }

    private void Image_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var image = (Image)sender;
        viewModel.ImageFiles.Remove(image.Source);
    }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ImageSource> ImageFiles { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<ImageSource>();

    public void LoadImages(IEnumerable<string> imageFiles)
    {
        ImageFiles.Clear();

        foreach (var imageFile in imageFiles)
        {
            var image = new BitmapImage();
            image.BeginInit();
            image.UriSource = new Uri(imageFile, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            image.DecodePixelWidth = 100;
            image.EndInit();
            ImageFiles.Add(image);
        }
    }
}
```

You may further improve this by replacing the Image with mouse event handler by a Button that uses an Image element in its ControlTemplate, and that has its Command property bound to an `ICommand` property in your view model. That command would remove the current image from the source collection.

Comment: I would like to ask how the case is if I want to wrap the WrapPanel in a ScrollViewer?

Comment: @TomFong Just put the whole ItemsControl inside a ScrollViewer. Make sure you disable horizontal scrolling.